# Adding Delay to Verilog Timing

Tags: fpga, verilog

I have a timing code, and on a trigger event,there is a 5 second countdown to activate a motor. Is it possible to add a delay of half a second in activating the output, or in the start of the countdown?

Comment: For synthesis or for a testbench?

Comment: For running it on FPGA.An actual delay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a small state machine. When event triggers, go to state 1, start a counter and wait for it to overflow (or hit a certain number which equals to your desired time); after that go to state 2 which will activate your output.